# How to fix ActiveAdmin specs error: stack level too deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, activeadmin

When I test my Rails App, ActiveAdmin specs failed.

GemFile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'
gem 'devise', '1.4.7'
gem 'kaminari', '0.12.4'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.2.2'
gem 'has_scope', '0.5.1', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope.git'
gem 'activeadmin', '0.3.2'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1', :group => [:test, :development]
[...]
```

Here's the error:

```
1) Admin logged in as admin should  login as admin
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   stack level too deep
 # /Users/francois/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24
```

I don't know how to fix this, any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting an infinite loop error.

Comment: ... well, I can read :-) This issue may be linked to ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I installed [search logic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) into my project.

I think it's because meta_search (which is required for active_admin) has similar method names which cause an infinite loop.

Double check the gems you're using and that none of the methods (or scopes) are conflicting.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Well, I'm using the gem 'meta_search' (version '1.1.1') required by ActiveAdmin, but I'll look after others method name conflicts...